# Set DIV to size of background-image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

So I am trying to figure out, how I can set the size of the second Box (see screenshot) to the size of the background image. I am using bootstrap and it's build flex classes. Maybe you guys can help me out here.

**Essentially what I would like to have is the purple box to be the same size of the background image and keep being the same size on resizing the screen.**

To test things out, I provided a prepared Stackblitz environment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/javascript-rs3ykl?file=index.html

[image]

```css
.page-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vh;
}

.background-image {
  background: url('https://dummyimage.com/258x362/007aa5?text=Banner-Desktop-Large') center center / contain no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  background-origin: content-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="row w-100 h-100">
    <div class="col-4 bg-primary">
      <p>Box 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="background-image">
        <div style="background: purple">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-around" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255)">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
              <div>Tage</div>
              <div>16086</div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
              <div>Stunden</div>
              <div class="">6</div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
              <div>Minuten</div>
              <div>13</div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
              <div>Sekunden</div>
              <div>34</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 bg-secondary">
      <p>Box 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need javascript to determine the aspect ratio of the image and adjust its CSS. I've made a [demo](https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/DpmnK) illustrating exactly that (drag bottom-right to resize it)

Comment: How about setting width: 100% and height:100% to the purple div?

Comment: If we do this the purple box will fill up the available space provided from flex, however we somehow need to get space from the background image. And also using javascript in this case will prob. not be a neat solution since we have server-side rendering in place and might cause content-layout-shift with this approach

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use image tag instead of url with div. so I changed it like this

```html
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<style>
  .page-container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 50vh;
  }

  .background-image {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    background-origin: content-box;
  }
  .bk-image {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="row w-100 h-100">
    <div class="col-4 bg-primary"><p>Box 1</p></div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="background-image">
        <div style="background: purple">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-around" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255)">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
              <div>Tage</div>
              <div>16086</div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
              <div>Stunden</div>
              <div class="">6</div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
              <div>Minuten</div>
              <div>13</div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
              <div>Sekunden</div>
              <div>34</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img class="bk-image" src = "https://dummyimage.com/258x362/007aa5?text=Banner-Desktop-Large">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 bg-secondary"><p>Box 3</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and now the purple bar stays with the background picture, also since you used height 100% I did it too but if you want it to stay inline with the row you can set the height as the same as row height.

Comment: If you check your solution in fullscreen, you see that the second box is not properly aligned with the other 2 boxes with in terms of height

Comment: as I said I did keep the height add 100% bc I though you just wanted it's width to be fixed but to fix the height too u just need to delete the " height : 100%; "  in .bk-image css styling